# Exception from HResult 0x80072EE7

Tags: c#, naudio

Что может означать ошибка Exception from HResult 0x80072EE7? Где это можно подсмотреть?

Конкретно ошибка возникает при использовании библиотеки NAudio, при вызове MediaFoundationReader.Read. Ниже мой код.

```
private void PlaceLinksIntoBuffer()
        {
            Uri baseUri = new Uri(InputPath);
            while (!IsStopped)
            {
                mediaSegmentUris.TryPeek(out IMediaSegment mediaSegment);
                if (mediaSegment == null) continue;

                int mediaSegmentApproximateDuration = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(mediaSegment.Duration));

                if (IsBufferNearlyFull(mediaSegmentApproximateDuration))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaSegmentUris.TryDequeue(out mediaSegment);
                    Uri resourceUri = new Uri(baseUri, mediaSegment.Uri);

                    MediaFoundationReader mediaFoundationReader;
                    try
                    {
                        mediaFoundationReader =
                            new MediaFoundationReader(resourceUri.AbsoluteUri);
                        readUris.Enqueue(mediaSegment.Uri);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        brokenUris.Enqueue(mediaSegment.Uri);
                        continue;
                    }

                    byte[] buffer = new byte [mediaFoundationReader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond *
                                              mediaSegmentApproximateDuration * 2];
                    int readBytes = mediaFoundationReader.Read(buffer, 0,
                        mediaFoundationReader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * mediaSegmentApproximateDuration * 2);

                    if (bufferedWaveProvider == null)
                    {
                        bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(mediaFoundationReader.WaveFormat)
                        {
                            BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mediaSegmentApproximateDuration * 5)
                        };
                    }

                    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    mediaFoundationReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Windos store open gives error 0x80072EE7, windows uppdate gives error 0x80072F8F (in windows log, in the windows just](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windos-store-open-gives-error-0x80072ee7-windows/09519a0b-75f2-4ce6-a3cb-660e4c0c8f39)

Comment: В Visual Studio есть в меню програмка, называется "Поиск ошибки", туда вбиваете данный код, узнаете что за ошибка.

Comment: Смотрела там, не находит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации, конечно. Однако процесс расшифровки кода ошибки в данном случае несколько нетривиален, так как это не "настоящий" HRESULT из COM (именно поэтому Exception.Message в C# и не выводит для него осмысленного сообщения, как, впрочем, и _com_error::ErrorMessage в С++).

Начать придется со [структуры HRESULT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx). Его можно разделить на 3 части:

1. **Биты 0-4: информационные флаги.** В данном случае S=1, что означает ошибку, остальные флаги не отмечены.
2. **Биты 5-15: тип ошибки.** У нас 7 = FACILITY_WIN32, т.е. это запакованный в HRESULT код ошибки Win32.
3. **Биты 16-31:код ошибки.**  У нас 0х2EE7 = 12007 в десятичной системе.

Расшифровку кода находим в [списке ошибок WinInet API](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/193625/info-wininet-error-codes-12001-through-12156):

> ERROR_INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> The server name could not be resolved

Таким образом, ошибка связана с разрешением доменных имен. При попытке обратиться к потоку, заданному по URL, NAudio внутренне использует WinInet для загрузки данных. WinInet не может разрешить имя сервера и возвращает эту ошибку.